# How can I modify this bash script to output to a specific folder?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I am modifying a script which gpg encrypts all files in a folder. As it currently stands it outputs the modified files to the same folder that the input files are in. However I would like to output to another directory that I define in the script. I have tried changing the output parameters in the script but I have not found the exact syntax yet. Any bash users in here that know what the syntax should be?

Vesa

```
#!/bin/bash

# This uses gpg to encrypt every file in a directory as separate
# encrypted files

# Usage
# ./encrypt-all.sh ./dir-of-files-to-encrypt "PASSPHRASE"

FILES="$1"
PASSPHRASE="$2"

pushd $FILES

for file_name in ./*; do
enc_name="$file_name.enc"

echo "Encrypting $file_name"

gpg \
--passphrase "$PASSPHRASE" \
--batch \
--output "$file_name.enc" \
--symmetric \
--cipher-algo AES256 \
"$file_name"

echo "Done! Output: $enc_name"
done

popd
```

Comment: Change this: `--output "$file_name.enc" \` to this:  `--output "/path/to/send/output/to/$file_name.enc" \`

Answer (score 1):

```
FILES="$1"
PASSPHRASE="$2"
OUTPUTPATH="/path/to/output/directory"

pushd $FILES

for file_name in ./*; do
    enc_name="$file_name.enc"

    echo "Encrypting $file_name"

    gpg \
    --passphrase "$PASSPHRASE" \
    --batch \
    --output "$OUTPUTPATH/$file_name.enc" \
    --symmetric \
    --cipher-algo AES256 \
    "$file_name"

    echo "Done! Output: $enc_name"
done

popd
```

Comment: Note that if `OUTPUTPATH` is specified as a relative path (i.e. not starting with "/"), it'll be treated as relative to the `FILES` directory; this may or may not be desirable. Also, I'd recommend double-quoting the reference to `$FILES`, in case it contains whitespace or wildcard characters (which are legal in unix filenames).